# what is the new deprecation date for azure ad graph api?

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I have been trying to find out the deprecation date for azure AAD Graph APIs. The below mentioned post says that the deprecation is in June 2022, but its postponed. I cannot find the new deprecation date anywhere. Is that announced already?

According to the blog post - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/update-your-applications-to-use-microsoft-authentication-library/ba-p/1257363,
It's mentioned that AAD Graph API will be deprecated by June 2022, and its postponed now. What is the new deprecation date?

Answer (score 0):

A Exact date has not been announced yet when Azure AD graph Finally will be deprecated as it was supposed to deprecated by June 30th 2020 but now it's extented its date and A follow up announcement will be published before 31 December 2022 with more information on additional tools to assist you with your migration and an updated retirement date.

Referennce :[**Update: Azure AD Graph retirement date**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/update-your-apps-to-use-microsoft-graph-before-30-june-2022/#:%7E:text=On%2030%20June%202022%2C%20we%27ll%20retire%20Azure%20AD%20Graph.)